# Reference object property as a method parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net

This won't work, but should give you an idea of what I'm trying to acheive:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, 
                               string param, string SomeProp)
{
    return entity.Where(l =>
    System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.PatIndex(param, l.SomeProp) > 0);
}
```

Do I have to pass the entire `Where()` parameter as a function to `MyMethod`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seeing your update, you can avoid repetition like this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> MyMethod<T>(this IEnumerable<T> entity, 
                               string param, Func<T, string> selector)
{
    return entity.Where(l =>
    System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.PatIndex(param, selector(l)) > 0);
}
```

Comment: return return won't compile.

Comment: Followup question: Is there any way to pass multiple properties? For example, I want to get `...PatIndex(param, l.SomeProp) > 0 && PatIndex(param, l.SomeOtherProp) > 0...` How would I pass that as the function?

Comment: @Johan:  You could achieve that by chaining calls. i.e. `collection.MyMethod("p1", t => t.Prop1).MyMethod("p2", t => t.Prop2)`